# Why does `?=` ("set if absent") cause make to unset an environment variable?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile as the following

```
.PHONY: check
check:
    ./check.sh

.PHONY: bar
bar: ENV_TEST ?= bar_env_test
bar:
    echo $(ENV_TEST)
```

and a script file (`check.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $ENV_TEST
echo $ENV_TEST_2
```

Firstly, I export both values of `ENV_TEST` and `ENV_TEST_2` variables

```
export ENV_TEST=env_test
export ENV_TEST_2=env_test_2
```

Then run `make check` and get the following output

```
./check.sh

env_test_2
```

the value of `ENV_TEST_2` was printed correctly but the value of `ENV_TEST` was empty.
My expected output is something like this

```
./check.sh
env_test
env_test_2
```

Does anyone know what happened to `ENV_TEST` environment variable?

Comment: FYI, you *wouldn't* have this problem if you ran `env ENV_TEST=$(ENV_TEST) ./check.sh` from your `check` target.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. Do you have any idea about this problem? Why does `?=` affect the result?

Comment: If I had an answer, I'd be *adding* an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: lol  :)) :)) :))

Answer (score 0):

This is *part of a response*:

When you add the `export` directive to the target-specific assignment, it will be ok:

```
check:
    @ ./check.sh

bar: export ENV_TEST ?= bar_env_test
bar:
    @ echo $(ENV_TEST)

.PHONY: check bar
```

And the result:

```sh
$ export ENV_TEST=env_test
$ export ENV_TEST_2=env_test_2
$ make check
env_test
env_test_2
$ make bar
env_test
$ unset ENV_TEST
$ make check

env_test_2
$ make bar
bar_env_test
```